# Download vagrant box file locally from atlas and configuring it

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I want to download a vagrant box file from Atlas for using it later locally with my vagrant file. How can I do this, and how can I configure it?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

To download a file you have to add version and provider in the URL. For example for downloading trusty64 First you need its URL which is 
https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/

then you have to add version and provider afterwards, for our example the download URL would be.

https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/20180206.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box

Then you have to add it locally from your vagrant file.

To add it locally to vagrant file use the following command

```
vagrant box add foo-box /path/to/vagrant-box.box
vagrant init foo-box
vagrant up
```

This will create the vagrantfile and you can configure the vagrant file.

Comment: This will not maintain the version number of the box locally. Online install does. It will keep showing that a new version is available, without an actual newer version being available. See below for fixing this issue.

Answer (score 28):

However, this will add the box as version 0.

```
○ → vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64 ~/Downloads/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box 
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'ubuntu/trusty64' (v0) for provider: 
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file:///Users/ram/Downloads/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box
==> box: Successfully added box 'ubuntu/trusty64' (v0) for 'virtualbox'!
```

vagrant does not allow to specify a version number of the manually added box

```
○ → vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64 ~/Downloads/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box --box-version 20151021.0.0
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
You specified a box version constraint with a direct box file
path. Box version constraints only work with boxes from Vagrant
Cloud or a custom box host. Please remove the version constraint
and try again.
```

To update the version number of the box, change the folder name '0' in ~/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64/0 to the version number you downloaded. For example '20160120.0.0'

```
 |2.2.3| MacBook-Pro in ~/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64
○ → mv 0 20160120.0.0
```

now you are all set to update the version next time with vagrant command too

```
○ → vagrant box list
ubuntu/trusty64 (virtualbox, 20160120.0.0)
```

Comment: vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' is up to date...
The box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' is not a versioned box. The box was added
directly instead of from a box catalog. Vagrant can only
check the versions of boxes that were added from a catalog
such as from the public Vagrant Server.

Comment: In order to avoid the problem described in @abuhurayra's comment, a `metadata_url` file needs to be added inside the `ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64` directory. The content of the file must be `https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/trusty64` in single line, without end-of-line character.

Comment: @WillingtonVega can you please update the above link as it is broken

Comment: @shankbond I think `https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64` is the new version of that URL, but can't really test whether it works right now. If that works, then for other outdated URLs you can replace `atlas.hashicorp.com` with `app.vagrantup.com` and add `boxes` between the box owner `ubuntu` and the box name `trusty64` (separated by `/`).

Answer (score 4):

**First**: check latest version from this link [**Here**](https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/boxes/homestead)

**Update**:you can try by go to the mentioned link above ,to get the number of latest version,then try to change the version in **bellow URL**
for now the latest version is:**7.2.1**
for virtualbox:
https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/7.2.1/providers/virtualbox.box
for hyperv:
https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/7.2.1/providers/hyperv.box
for vmware:
https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/7.2.1/providers/vmware_desktop.box
for parallels:
https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/7.2.1/providers/parallels.box
**Maybe** in the **future** the link changed so try to get download vagrant box by using command on your terminal/CMD by command

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

choose your virtualization method
then you will see the download link **ended with *.box**, after that you can cancel it **CTRL+C** and copy the **download link**  and download it locally by using **IDM/aria2c -x16** etc.
**Second**: Use this command

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead {Path of file from your local computer}
```

**Third**:add metadata by go to
1- you create a file called **metadata_url**
NOTE: There is no extension for metadata_url

2- Then add this link and save the file

```
https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead
```

3- Copy metadata_url file to:

- for **windows** go to

  %userprofile%.vagrant.d\boxes\laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead

4- Then rename the folder named **0** to the version of the current homestead version = **7.2.1**

I hope this help
for more information 
[Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead)
[metadata](https://laravel.io/forum/05-06-2015-how-to-download-vagrant-box-manually)

Comment: the laravel/homestead box download link takes to a 404 page. here is the link that works: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/6.3.0/providers/virtualbox.box

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue not being able to download from script. So manually downloaded the box and added to vagrant as below,

you can get versions you want from here - https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/precise64

```
wget https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/precise64/versions/20160818.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box

cd my_vagrant_project
vagrant box add precise64 ~/Downloads/precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box

vagrant init precise64
vagrant up
```

Answer (score 4):

**Download virtualbox.box:**

```
https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/6.4.0/providers/virtualbox.box
```

You can change the version(6.4.0) of homestead box with the Current Version.

***Current version: 6.4.0.***

Check for the latest version here: https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/boxes/homestead

> After downloading the box, rename it to virtualbox.box

Don't forget to include the .box extension.

**Add the downloaded homestead box to vagrant:**

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead file:///f:/virtualbox.box
```

Change the Drive( `c: or d: or e:`) or Path(`c:/folder1/folder2/virtualbox.box`) to the location where you have stored your downloaded homestead box.

**You will get success massage like image below:**

[image: success image]

**Update homestead box**

Navigate to vagrant directory:

> c:/users/YourUserName/.vagrant.d/boxes/laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead

After that, Create a file called `metadata_url`

> **NOTE:** There is no extension for metadata_url

Then add the link below and save the file

```
https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/homestead
```

Do not add a newline after link in above file.

> Rename folder 0 to 6.4.0

***6.4.0 is your homestead box version.***

And it's Done. Hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64 folder from someone else machine you can simply copy paste the folder to

```
~/.vagrant.d/boxes
```

and use the `vagrant up` to start the servers. This way you **do not need** to add the trusty64 [box manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28399325/3168721).

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for OSX/Fusion:

```
wget https://vagrantcloud.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise64/versions/1.1.0/providers/vmware_fusion.box
# For some reason, the downloaded filename was set to an uuid
# mv <uuid> vmware_fusion.box
vagrant box add hashicorp/precise64 vmware_fusion.box
cd vagrant.d/boxes/hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-precise64
mv 0 1.1.0
echo -n "https://app.vagrantup.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise64" > metadata_url
vagrant box list
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to use `vagrant up` and I got URL to download box file:

https://vagrantcloud.com/centos/boxes/7/versions/1801.02/providers/virtualbox.box

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: `atlas.hashicorp.com` not woking. We should use `vagrantcloud.com`