# Can't add Vagrant scotchbox

Tags: bash, ssl, curl, virtualbox, vagrant-windows

I am facing issues while setting up the scotch box on my system. The OS I am using is Windows 8.1 pro 64 bit operating system, using git bash.

`$ vagrant --version 
Vagrant 1.8.6`

`VirtualBox-5.1.6`

After cloning the repo from github for scotch box I do vagrant up as mentioned in the notes. It gives me the following error:

`$ vagrant up`

`default: An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.`

`SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html`

`curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.`
`If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).`
`If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.`

I have tried the insecure options, which gives me this error:

`bsdtar.EXE: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format`

Also I have tried reinstalling vagrant, and virtual box but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an alternative way of doing this, added scotch box manually,  [add vagrant box manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399324/download-vagrant-box-file-locally-from-atlas-and-configuring-it) and then cloned the [scotch-repo](https://github.com/scotch-io/scotch-box). modified the vagrant file as per the repo, and did vagrant up. It worked fine, but still have raised this issue on github as well.