# Install manual for laravel homestead with virtualbox.box

Tags: php, laravel, virtualbox, homestead

https://medium.com/@eaimanshoshi/i-am-going-to-write-down-step-by-step-procedure-to-setup-homestead-for-laravel-5-2-17491a423aa

I followed this documentation and its always failing when running this command *vagrant box add laravel/homestead*

So I decided to install vagrant box manually.

I have this url https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.5.0/providers/virtualbox.box to download vagrant box but I have received *404 Not Found*

And this link I followed to manually install virtual box https://gist.github.com/idecardo/deec25b8fa54976edb496d7ce7d320a7

Anyone can help me with this? Where I can find the virtualbox.box to download?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This may Help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399324/download-vagrant-box-file-locally-from-atlas-and-configuring-it/53577869#53577869

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can download virtualbox.box from

```
https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/6.4.0/providers/virtualbox.box
```

Change the version of homestead box. Current version: 6.4.0.

Check for the latest version here: https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/boxes/homestead

After downloading the box, rename it to `virtualbox.box`

> Don't forget to include the .box extension.

Add the downloaded homestead box to vagrant:

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead /path/to/virtualbox.box
```

Change the path to where you stored your downloaded homestead box.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

Running *vagrant box add laravel/homestead* download slowly and will eventually timeout.

So i manually downloaded it thru this link:
[laravel homestead](https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/boxes/homestead)

Hope it help.